# Is there a way to fade between two icon states in a button in React?

Tags: css, reactjs, css-transitions

So I have like a hamburger nav bar icon, when clicked the icon changes from a hamburger to a minus. The state logic is just a setState function placed in the NavToggle component (button) like this.

```
      <NavToggle onClick={() => setToggle(!toggle)}><Icon icon={toggle ? faBars : faMinus}></Icon></NavToggle>
```

And the icon changes in the icon component inside. I cant think of a simple way to fade in between these two. I dont like how snappy the change between them is so I'd really like to implement a slower transition.

Comment: Render both items and only change their opacity.
Then set opacity according to toggle.

Comment: ooo thats a good idea, ill look into it thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to create a class and add it to your icon component.

```
//CSS
    .nameOfClass{
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out
    }
//JS
<Icon icon={toggle ? faBars : faMinus} className="nameOfClass"/>
```

Comment: Nah that doesnt work cuz the icon change isnt a transition per so. Its a whole component change